# Proof of the Coherence of Monoids in a monoidal category (Final Edit)

Tags: category-theory

This is not Maclane's Coherence theorem; rather, a variant. I would like a critique of step 2 of my attempted proof.

Let $B=\left ( B,\square, \alpha ,\lambda ,\varrho , \right )$ be a moinodal category; let $c= \left ( c, \mu ,\eta  \right )$ be a monoid in B. Define a multiplication on $c$ by recursion: if $W$ is the monoidal category of binary words, then

$\mu _{e_{0}}=\eta :e\rightarrow c;\\ \mu _{\left ( - \right )}=1_{c}:c\rightarrow c;\\\mu _{\left ( -\square - \right )}=\mu $

and in general, for words $u,v\in W: \mu _{_{u\square v}}=\mu \left ( \mu _{u} \square \mu _{v}\right )$

Now, take as "basic arrows" in $W$ all instances of $1, \alpha ,\lambda ,\varrho ,\mu ,\eta $ and their derivates "boxed in" by $1$. Then, I claim there is a coherence theorem in this situation which says that any two paths $u\rightarrow \left ( - \right )$ in the graph whose vertices are words in $W$ and edges composites of basic arrows $u_{c}\rightarrow v_{c}$ in $B$, are actually the same.

What got me thinking about this is, I know Maclane's Coherence Theorem and I just started to wonder if you'd get some similar result using "basic arrows" in $\eta $ and $\mu $ in addition to the other ones, and as I was playing around with this, I noticed that basic arrows (in $\eta $ and $\mu $), $\beta :y_{c}\rightarrow z_{c}$ immediately preceding $z_{c}$ seemed to satisfy $\mu _{y}=\mu _{z}\circ \beta $. If true in general, this would imply a coherence result for "basic arrows" in $\mu, \beta , \alpha , \lambda ,\varrho$. Here is my proof. Interestingly, this won't work if the last word is not $(-)$.

Here is my attempt:

Step 1: Let $u_{c}\rightarrow c$ be as advertised. By using suitable natural transformations and identities, this arrow is the same as $u_{c}\overset{f(\alpha ,\lambda ,\varrho )}{\rightarrow} w_{c}\overset{g(\mu ,\eta )}{\rightarrow}c$ where $f$ is evidently the canonical arrow given by the coherence theorem for $B$.

Step 2: Let $z_{c}$ be any element of $B$ s.t $w_{c}\rightarrow z_{c}\rightarrow c$. Now let $\beta :y_{c}\rightarrow z_{c}$ be the basic arrow immediately preceding the arrow $z_{c}\rightarrow c$. I claim that $\mu _{y}=\mu _{z}\circ \beta $:

Let $n$ be the maximum word length,  $l$,  in the set of composites in the arrow $z_{c}\rightarrow c$. If $n=1$, then either $z_{c}=e$, in which case $z_{c}\rightarrow c$ is $\eta $, and there is no previuos arrow, or $z_{c}=c$, in which case the arrow $z_{c}\rightarrow c$ is $1_{c}$ and the previous one is $\mu $. So, suppose the claim is true for all maximum lengths $<n$ and consider $y_{c}\overset{\beta }{\rightarrow}z_{c}\overset{\mu _{z}}{\rightarrow}c$, where the maximum word length in the set of composites from $z_{c}$ to $c$ is $n$.

We may assume that $\beta \neq \mu $. This implies that $\beta =1_{u}\square \beta '$ or $\beta =\beta '\square 1_{u}$, for some basic arrow $\beta '$. wlog the former case. Then

$y_{c}=u_{c}\square v_{c}\overset{1_{u}\square \beta '}{\rightarrow}u_{c}\square v'_{c}=z_{c}\overset{\mu _{z}}{\rightarrow}c$.

Now we get:

$\mu_{y}=\mu \left ( \mu {_{u}}\square \mu _{v} \right )\\\mu_{z}=\mu \left ( \mu {_{u}}\square \mu _{v'} \right )\\\mu _{z}\left ( 1_{u_{c}} \square \beta '\right )=\mu \left ( \mu_{u} \square (\mu _{v'}\circ \beta ' \right) )$.

If $l(u_{c})\neq 0$, then $l(v')< l(z)\leqslant n$ and the inductive hypothesis allows us to write $\mu _{v'}\circ \beta '=\mu _{v}$ and we are done.

If $l(u_{c})=0$ and $v'_{c}=c$, then $l(v'_{c})=1$ and the next arrow in the sequence must have length equal to 2, and so the inductive hypothesis applies again. Otherwise, $z_{c}=u _{c}\square (r_{c}\square s_{c})$. Then, $\beta ' $ is an arrow $v_{c}\rightarrow r_{c}\square s_{c}$ and as $\beta '$ is basic, $v_{c}$ must be either of the form  $r_{c}\square a_{c}$ or $a_{c}\square s_{c}$. wlog the former, so that $\beta '=1_{r_{c}}\square \beta ''$ for some other basic arrow $\beta ''$. Then,

$\mu _{z}=\mu (\mu _{u}\square \mu _{r\square s})=\mu (\mu _{u}\square \left ( \mu \left ( \mu _{r} \square \mu _{s}\right ) \right ))\\\mu _{y}=\mu \left ( \mu _{u}\square \mu _{v} \right )=\mu \left ( \mu _{u}\square \mu_{r\square a} \right )=\mu (\mu _{u} \square \mu \left ( \mu _{r} \square \mu _{a}\right ))\\\mu (\mu _{u} \square \mu \left ( \mu _{r} \square \mu _{a}\right ))\circ \left ( 1_{e}\square \left ( 1_{r_{c}}\square \beta '' \right ) \right )=\mu (\mu _{u}\square \left ( \mu \left ( \mu _{r} \square \mu _{a}\circ \beta ''\right ) \right ))$.

Now, if $l(r_{c})\neq 0$, we invoke the inductive hypothesis to assert that $\mu _{s}=\mu _{a}\circ \beta ''$, and we are done. If $l(r_{c})=0$, we repeat this process, finding a $\beta '''$, etc., applying the inductive hypothesis if we can and if not, repeating the process again, which must terminate because there are a finite number of instances of $e$.Therefore, $g=\mu _{w}$ and we are done.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to ask my question which is: my proof seems to be too involved. Is there an simpler one that uses only basic concepts?

Comment: Is this [link](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Mac+Lane%27s+proof+of+the+coherence+theorem+for+monoidal+categories) related to your question?

Comment: Not really. Please see my edit above for details. Thanks you.

Comment: @Chilango, **please** edit the question text and put the actual question there!