# Universality of the Simplex Category. Proving Functoriality of the Map.

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, monoidal-categories

Let $B$ be a strict monoidal category, and $\left \langle c,\mu ',\eta ' \right \rangle$ a monoid in $B$. Now suppose we consider the simplex category $\left \langle \triangle ,+,0 \right \rangle$, the monoid $\left \langle 1,\mu ,\eta \right \rangle$and define $F:\Delta \rightarrow B$ in the obvious way:

On objects take

$Fn=c^{n}$ (so that in particular $F0=\eta $ and $F1=c$.

On arrows, note that if $f:m\rightarrow n=$ then $f=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mu ^{m_{i}}$ with $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}m_{i}=m$ and $f(j)=i$ if $j\in m_{i}$, for all $0\leq j\leq m-1$, so it makes sense to set

$Ff=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\mu' )^{m_{i}}$

Now let $g:n\rightarrow k$ so that $g=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\mu ^{n_{i}}$, with $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}n_{i}=n$ and $g(j)=i$ if $j\in n_{i}$, for all $0\leq j\leq k-1$.

My problem is proving that $F$ is a functor. That is, that $F(g)F(f)=F(gf)$. This amounts to showing  that

$(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mu ^{m_{i}})(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\mu ^{n_{i}})$ composes in the same way as $(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\mu ') ^{m_{i}})(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(\mu ')^{n_{i}})$.

I thought this would be an easy application of the associative law, which holds in any strict monoidal category, namely:

Let $k_{1},k_{2},\cdots, k_{n}$ be any set of $n$ integers. Then,

$\mu ^{n}(\left ( \mu ^{k_{1}} \otimes \mu ^{k_{2}}\right )\otimes \cdots \mu ^{k_{n}})=\mu ^{k_{1}+k_{2}+\cdots +k_{n}}$.

I have tried using the associative law on this, but it is clear that, by itself, it won't do because each side is an arrow with codomain $c$.

I have tried considering the product $Fgf$ written $Fgf:c^{m}\rightarrow c^{k}$, $Fgf=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(\mu ')^{m'_{i}}$, with $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}m'_{i}=m$ and $Fgf(j)=i$ if $j\in m'_{i}$, for all $0\leq j\leq k-1$. Then I need to show that

$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(\mu ')^{m'_{i}}=(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\mu ') ^{m_{i}})(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(\mu ')^{n_{i}})$. But I have not been able to prove this, although there are interesting relations here using the definitions of the $m _{i},m' _{i}$ and $n _{i}$.

I do have $\mu ^{k}(\mu '^{m'_{0}}\otimes \cdots \otimes \mu '^{m'_{k-1}})=\mu ^{k}(\mu '^{m_{0}}\otimes \cdots \otimes \mu '^{m_{n-1}})(\mu '^{n_{0}}\otimes \cdots \otimes \mu '^{n_{k-1}})$ and so I tried induction on $k$, but to no avail.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Note: The associative law follows from setting $\mu _{e}=\eta, \mu _{c}= 1_{c}, \mu _{c\otimes c}=\mu $ and thereafter $\mu _{u_{c}\otimes v_{c}}=\mu(\mu _{u_{c}}\otimes \mu _{v_{c}})$ Then, the multiplication is, using the notation for powers of $c$, $\mu ^{0}= \eta $, $\mu ^{1}=1_{c}$, $\mu ^{2}=\mu $, and thereafter, $\mu ^{n+1}=\mu \left ( \mu ^{n} \otimes 1\right )$. From this you get the result in a strict monoidal category.

Comment: Your last summation is the correct condition to check.

Comment: Try writing the left side as a nested sum.

Comment: I did try to do that but it got very messy, I wrote each term as a nested sum and then tried to combine them. No luck though!

Comment: I guess I am missing something basic becuase I haven't been able to work with the nested sum. But then, noting that $\mu ^{k}(\mu '^{m'_{0}}\otimes \cdots \otimes \mu '^{m'_{k-1}})=\mu ^{k}(\mu '^{m_{0}}\otimes \cdots \otimes \mu '^{m_{n-1}})(\mu '^{n_{0}}\otimes \cdots \otimes \mu '^{n_{k-1}})$ I tried to use induction on $k$ also without success.

Comment: Could you give me a second hint before I send this to bounty? I'm stumped!

Comment: You ask questions that shouldn't be hard but are. Either that, or know less than I think.

Comment: Asing them is a good thing though.

Comment: I am trying to teach myself from CWM and I like to dot the i's and cross the t's!

Answer (score 0):

Mac Lane showed on page 171 of "categories for working mathematicians" that any combination of multiplications lead to the same function, if they have the same domain, and their codomain is the monoid, via coherence. Since both $F(g \circ h)$ and $F(g) \circ F(h)$ are combinations of multiplications, they are equal via that theorem.

His proof goes along the lines of that, since the basic associative laws are in terms of the distributor and two unitors, any two iterated products would be various combinations of them, making the result a canonical arrow.

Comment: But the multiplications can not be reduced to the "basic arrows" of the coherence thm (for monoids, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260858/proof-of-the-coherence-of-monoids-in-a-monoidal-category-final-edit), which are instances of $\mu $ and $\eta $ and their derivates "boxed in" by $1$, like $(1\otimes (1\otimes \mu))$. That is, they must be binary products, with only one instance of $\mu $ or $\eta $. When you expand the products here, they don't reduce to compositions of these. At least, not that I could see!

Comment: @Chilango I was talking about is monoid coherence.

Comment: I only know coherence theorems for monoids in a monoida category, of the form in which the arrows are $1, \lambda, \rho ,\mu, \alpha$ and derivates boxed in by $1$. I'm going to go on and hopefully come back to this when I get a better handle on the ideas.

Comment: @Chilango There is also moniod coherence. Endocanonical arrows are id.

Comment: @Could you give me a reference?

Comment: @Chilango Edited into the answer

Comment: On p171 in the 2d edition, there is the statement that n-fold products are all equal, but these are arrows :$w_{c}\rightarrow c$ for $c$ a monoid in $B$. Our products are more general, and the result we want s not true for all monoids is it? In fact, exercise 2 p 173 illustrates this.

Comment: @Chilango Aren't these arrows just different kinds of n folds? That is how the Functor is defined.